# Plesk Config Apache with a Domain.tld/site

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, plesk, vhosts

There is a Domain Forwarding domain.com/site to our Plesk. The Problem is, that Plesk i.e Apache doesn´t recognize this domain. We don`t know how to set up our Apache configs that the domain is registered by Plesk.

We already set up vhosts, but the problem was not figured out.

```
#/var/www/vhosts/system/domain.com/conf/vhost_ssl.conf
ServerName "integ.domain.com:443"
ServerAlias "www.integ.domain.com/site"
ServerAlias "ipv4.integ.domain.com/site"
UseCanonicalName On

<Directory /var/www/vhosts/bdomainsdvre>
    Options +FollowSymLinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Comment: Have you registered this domain via Plesk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have solve this issue**. plesk manged that completely automatically. 
the issue was not apache or plesk! it was only a wrong ip address on the forwarding url.

My problem was that I could not check the ip address with nslookup or ping.

```
nslookup domain.com/site
** server can't find domain.com/site: NXDOMAIN
```

the command `dig` has helped me.

```
dig domain/site
```